# zsh wants to correct vim to .vim

Tags: zsh, sudo, gentoo, line-editor

I'm using zsh on Gentoo x64, and when I type `sudo vim /path/to/file`  from my home folder, zsh asks:

```
zsh: correct 'vim' to '.vim' [nyae]?
```

I want to run `vim` not my `.vim` folder.  How do I fix this?

My guess is that `setopt autocd` is causing this.  Odd thing is, if I don't add `sudo`, zsh doesn't ask to correct anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try `alias sudo='nocorrect sudo'`.

Comment: `nocorrect`, eh?  Does that just ignore corrections for just that command?  I'll have to test this out later.

Answer (score 16):

OK, I got this. The problem isn't `autocd`, it's `correctall`. `vim` as a command (`vim file`) doesn't trigger any correction*, but `vim` in `sudo vim` is an argument, `zsh` sees that it's close to the name of a folder in the current directory, and asks if you want to change to that, as files and folders are more common arguments. So the solution is `unsetopt correctall` (or `setopt nocorrectall`). As illustration; note I have a `.zsh` folder:

```
% unsetopt correctall
% setopt autocd correct 
% vim zsh
% sudo vim zsh
% setopt correctall
% vim zsh
zsh: correct 'zsh' to '.zsh' [nyae]? 
% sudo vim zsh
zsh: correct 'zsh' to '.zsh' [nyae]? 
zsh: correct 'vim' to '.vim' [nyae]? 
%
```

<sub>*: Or shouldn't, I have had zsh ask if it should correct `command` to `_command` on a couple commands for some reason. Perhaps because it checks aliases and gives them higher priority.</sub>

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  I kinda like having `correctall` on, because I can't type, and I like how it'll correct `ks` to `ls`.  Wonder if there's a way to change how zsh checks for "corrections".